# For an universal set $U$, prove or disprove, for sets $A,B,C \subseteq U, A \cap C = B \cap C \implies A = B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I've tried to solve the question in two different ways :

1. Using Characteristic function(CF).

$$CF(A) = \{ 1, x \in A \text{ ; } 0, \text{elsewhere}\}$$ 
$$CF(B) = \{ 1, x \in B \text{ ; } 0, \text{elsewhere} \}$$
$$CF(C) = \{ 1, x \in C \text{ ; } 0, \text{elsewhere} \}$$

Since, $$A \cap C = B \cap C $$
$$CF(A) * CF(B) = CF(B) * CF (C)$$
$$\text{Therefore, } CF(A) = CF(B)$$ 
$$\implies A=B$$

1. Consider the following counter example :

   Let $$A = \{1,2,3\} , B = \{2,3,4,5\} , C = \{2,3\}.$$
   $$A \cap C = \{2,3\} \text{ and } B \cap C = \{2,3\} \text{ but } A \neq B.$$
   Hence disproved by counter example.

Which one is correct ? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement $A \cap C = B \cap C \implies A = B$ is false.

Your conclusion that "Therefore, $CF(A) = CF(B)$" is false, since you didn't consider the possibility of dividing by zero.

Your counterexample is sufficient to disprove the statement. Also, I would suggest considering three disjoint sets $A, B, C$. In this case, $A \cap C = \varnothing = B \cap C$, yet $A \neq B$

Comment: I'm studying this concept in school; only there's  bit more to this shown here than I've learnt so far.

Comment: @David: I'm not sure I get what you're trying to say. Would you like me to elaborate?

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you please elaborate how o disprove using characteristic functions i.e. by considering dividing by 0 ?

Comment: @Sunil   How do you go from $CF(A) * CF(C) = CF(B) * CF (C)$ to Therefore $CF(A)=CF(B)$? ;)

Answer (score 5):

A picture might help with this one too: [image]

Answer (score 3):

And, of course, if $C = \varnothing$ then $A \cap C = B \cap C = \varnothing$
for any $A$ and $B$.